# Parse data from web service using Invoke-RestMethod and save as CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I use `Invoke-RestMethod` to get data from web and export to csv. I have a need to insert a calculation field and remove two fields. My following code yield nothing, why?

```
$request = "www.oanda.com/rates/api/v1/rates/USD.csv?quote=CNY&quote=EUR&quote=GBP&quote=KRW&fields=averages&api_key=Yv0C4DZ2rFOybbnGwzj7niFh"    
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -OutFile "C:\curr.csv"        
# remove header    
$currencys = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $request    
$currencys = $currencys[1..($currencys.count - 1)]     
$(    
write-host "base,","curr,","date,","bid,","ask"    
foreach($currency in $currencys){    
  $base = $($currency.base_currency)    
  $curr = $($currency.currency)    
  $date = $($currency.date)    
  $bid = $($currency.bid)    
  $ask = $($currency.ask)    
  $average = ($bid + $ask)/2.0    
  $line =  $curr + "," + $date + "," + $bid + "," + $average   
  write-host $line    
}  
) | export-csv test.csv
```

Comment: The original data file looks like below:  
base,currency,date,bid,ask  
USD,CNY,2015-05-28T21:00:00+0000,6.08980,6.12680  
USD,EUR,2015-05-28T21:00:00+0000,0.91592,0.91606   
USD,GBP,2015-05-28T21:00:00+0000,0.65239,0.65249  
USD,KRW,2015-05-28T19:00:00+0000,1107.05000,1109.75000

Comment: The `$request` does not look correct. Should we be able to browse to that and see the file? You have your API key in there which might be a bad idea.

Comment: Main problem is you are using `write-host` which rights to console... not the output stream. Other things could be improved but change those lines to `write-Output` for starters/

Comment: The api_key is expired. Let me see if I can get another one. But it works OK using my productin api_key to replace this one.

Comment: In the question that `$request` has a group of several spaces.

Comment: I tried write-output before but it output nothing. I tried write_output $base and it yields nothing.

Comment: The space is my format problem and I had very bad time to post this question. This quorum requires so much format which I am not familiar with. There should not be a space there.